ARM's TrustZone preemptiveness
When the processor is running in the Secure World, it generally remains in control until it voluntarily switches back to the Non-Secure World. This process is typically triggered by an explicit Secure Monitor Call (SMC) from the Non-Secure World or a return from a Secure operation.
In this setup, the Secure World is non-preemptive because it decides when to give up control.
I've came across this ARM's documentation:

In a TrustZone system there are two software stacks, one for Non-secure state and another for Secure state. A processor core can only be in one
state at a time. Who decides when each world is allowed to run?
Explicit calls to the EL3 firmware, like power management requests using Power State Coordination Interface (PSCI), are typically blocking. This
means that control will only be returned to Non-secure state when the requested operation is complete. However, these calls tend to be short and
infrequent.
The TEE typically runs under the control of the Non-secure state OS scheduler. A possible design is to have a daemon running under the OS as a
place holder for the TEE. When the daemon is scheduled by the OS, the daemon hands control to the TEE through an SMC. The TEE then runs,
processing outstanding requests, until the next scheduler tick or interrupt. Then control returns to the Non-secure state OS.

I am trying to understand how come that on one hand ARM's TZ is non-preemptive, while on the other hand, there's an option to run TEE from a userspace's daemon, and somehow get TZ preempted?

Pre-emption in the 2nd case is voluntary.  So, it is co-operative.  The SMC/TEE that runs until the next scheduler tick or interrupt, must yield the CPU at this point.  So, the very last part is not true ..and somehow get TZ preempted.  This is an explicit yield from secure to the normal world.  With co-operative pre-emption, the TrustZone is 'still in control', depending on the security model.  For instance, monitor mode can handle IRQs and decide whether to return to the normal world to let the interrupts be handled (if they are not masked); Complexity and attack surface increase.

I would suggest modelling with spin/promela or some other tool if you implement this.

How can Secure world be aware of the Normal world's scheduler tick? It seems it requires difining a new interrupt to Secure world that'll be sent by normal world's timer?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but normally, secure world won't be aware of normal world's hw clock. Instead, secure will be using the secure clock.
With, I think that on the other side it doesn't work the same - Secure timer can cause the normal world to be interrupted.

The monitor mode with get an IRQ (normal interrupt).  FIQ can be locked as secure interrupts.  So the reception of an IRQ indicates a TICK or other interrupt source in the normal world.  The monitor must transition to the normal world (or it could stay in the secure world); this is where the choice was made to allow (not mask) IRQs.  The monitor will be in 'normal world' space and can access GIC, etc to determine the interrupt source (if that is the design).

it requires difining a new interrupt to Secure world that'll be sent by normal world's timer?  A misconception.  When in secure mode, all accesses transition through monitor mode.  This include IRQs which vector to the monitor mode code and not the normal world.  I think you can follow from that point?
